# Shadows not reaching all the way to the ground in Eeevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

Take a look at the shadow cast by the leg on the sofa in the foreground. Even though the object is touching my shadowcaster surface, the bottom part of the leg casts no shadow.

Larger objects seem to cast shadows just fine, but table & chair legs pose a problem! Any suggestions as to how to approach this would be MUCH appreciated!

(This is some virtual staging for a real estate listing.)
[image: Sofa leg shadow doesn't reach the "ground"]

[image]

Comment: have you enabled the Contact Shadows option of the light?

Comment: Hey, that did it! An option I never even knew existed, "contact shadows"! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Enable the *Shadow > Contact Shadows* option of the light:

[image]

Also for the shadows quality, take a look at the *Shadows* in the *Render* panel (and increase the *Sampling* value):

[image]

Comment: Uploaded a new pic - much better shadows. Moved some lights around a bit, too. 

I knew how to tweak for shadow quality already, just needed that nudge toward "contact shadows". Always so many details to know in Blender - I'd be lost without this forum!

Comment: yes Eevee gives headache sometimes, but I guess it's the price to pay  ;)

Comment: Yup! Now I need to fix that damn carpeting...

:)